# send CRC command through the serial port using java

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

is there any  way to send CRC command through serial port from one PC to another one using Java!

here is the code to connect to the port and open it...

```
public class Write {

static Enumeration portList;
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static String messageString = "\n";
static SerialPort serialPort;
static OutputStream outputStream;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM1")) {
                try {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Embedded", 8000);
                    System.out.println("openning the port...");
                } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                }
                try {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("sending the command...");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                }
                try {
                    outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
                    serialPort.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send command to embedded pc connected by serial port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938630/how-to-send-command-to-embedded-pc-connected-by-serial-port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already have the harder part of the code, the serial-port write. Now all you need is to calculate the crc and place it in your `outputStream.write`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html